# Single vs. Double Dirac Potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, dirac-delta-distributions

Both single and double Dirac potentials have an even ground state solution.
Supposing the 'strengths' $\alpha$ of the single and double Dirac potentials to be the same, i.e., supposing
$V_{single} = -\alpha \delta (0)$ and
$V_{double} = -\alpha (\delta(0) + \delta(l))$ ,
I have derived that the energy of the even ground state in the double Dirac potential is *less than* (i.e., more negative) than that of the single Dirac potential. Why would this be so physically? Why would the ground state wavefunction be 'more tightly' bound in the double Dirac potential well than in the single one?

Comment: For all $x$, $V_{double}(x) \le V_{single}(x)$, so for any given state the expectation of the energy with $V_{double}$ will be less than with $V_{single}$. Indeed it we can in fact say it will be less by exactly $\alpha|\psi(l)|^2$. The question is how much lower beyond this is the new ground state

Comment: @BySymmetry Would the two differ by exactly $\alpha |\psi(l)|^2$, if the kinetic energy of a ground-state particle in the single and double potential wells also differs?

Comment: $\alpha|\psi(l)|^2$ is the difference if you take expectation of the same wavefunction with both potentials. The ground states will have different wavefunction, but the expectation of the 'wrong' ground state will always be greater than the ground state energy, so you can say that the difference between the two ground states will be bigger than this

Comment: Have you encountered the [variational principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variational_method_(quantum_mechanics))